# Apply Spring task-scheduler to multiple instances of same Bean using Annotation

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, java-8, scheduled-tasks

I have one class Task with a @Scheduled method as below

```
public class Task{
 public void task(){}
}
```

TaskConfig creates 2 different beans of same class :

```
public class TaskConfig{
 @Bean("task1")
 public Task getTask1(){return new Task();}

 @Bean("task2")
 public Task getTask1(){return new Task();}
}
```

Using xml based configuration I can create 2 scheduler for same method as below, which will run at differenct time. :

```
<task:scheduled-tasks >       
        <task:scheduled ref="task1"    method="task"           cron="*/5 * * * * ?" />
        <task:scheduled ref="task2"    method="task"           cron="*/30 * * * * ?" />
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

But how to achieve this same scenario in Spring 5 Annotation based ? Please suggest.Thanks in advance !

Comment: Inject the `TaskScheduler` and manually schedule the tasks, don't use `@Scheduled` then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `@Scheduled` annotation and annotate your method you want to execute: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support You can also define cron like expressions.

You should also make sure the scheduling is enabled: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableScheduling.html

**EDIT**:

```
public class TaskConfig{
 @Bean("task1")
 public Task getTask1(){return new Task() {
   @Override
   @Scheduled
   public void task(){super.task();}
 };
}

 @Bean("task2")
 public Task getTask2(){return new Task() {
   @Override
   @Scheduled
   public void task(){super.task();}
 };
}
```

Comment: Thanks v_schoener for your reply, but if you go through my question , its about applying 2 different cron to 2 different instance of Bean of same class and same 'schdueler' method. I mentioned the xml based solution to in my question itself , but need to get an annotation based solution for the same .

Comment: Please check the added **edit** and try it this way.